# Send array from php to AJAX response

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to filter state, zones of Nepal using ajax. I have got them in MySQL database.

I have populated zone select box initially, it is okay.

```
<select class="district col-md-3 center-block" id="zone">
<?php 
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_zones)) {
        echo "<option value='".$res['name']."'>".$res['name']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Now What I am trying is when user changes zone, I need all districts associated with this zone from districts table.

What I have done is here:

**Ajax call**

```
<script>
        $(document.body).on("change","#zone",function(){
            //console.log(this.value);
            $.ajax({
                dataType : 'json',
                async: false,
                url:'process.php?zone_id=' + this.value,
                complete: function (response) {
                    var result = JSON.stringify(response.data);//parsing status from response received from php
                    console.log(result);
                }
               });
        });
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['zone_id'])) {
      $arr =array();
      $zone_id=$_GET['zone_id'];
      $i=0;
      $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM districts WHERE zone_id = '$zone_id'");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
      }
      // preparing correct format for json_encode
      header('Content-type: application/json'); 
      echo json_encode(array('data' => $arr)); //sending response to ajax
    }
 ?>
```

When I go through url `http://localhost/nepal-locations/process.php?zone_id=8`, I'm getting data as I need like below:

```
{"data":[{"id":"42","name":"Mustang","zone_id":"8"},{"id":"43","name":"Myagdi","zone_id":"8"},{"id":"44","name":"Parbat","zone_id":"8"},{"id":"45","name":"Baglung","zone_id":"8"}]}
```

But I'm getting data empty in console.

```
{data: []}
data
:
[]
```

What might be wrong I'm doing?

**Update:**
output console.log(response)
[image]

Comment: what's the console.log output if you do var result = response.data; without the json stringify ?

Comment: @Bdloud It's undefined

Comment: And a console.log of response ?

Comment: `echo "<option value='".$res['name']."'>".$res['name']."</option>";` may be you need `id` instead of `name` in `option value`

Comment: Please try just `JSON.stringify(response)` not `response.data`

Comment: @Bdloul I've updated with screenshot of console.log(response)

Comment: @SureshPokharel oh sorry I didn't notice it's the complete callback , I was thinking it's the success callback which has data as it's first parameter.

Comment: @SureshPokharel have you check url? You need to pass ID while you are passing name in ajax. CHeck my previous comment, It will help you

Comment: @B.Desai OMG Thanks a lot man. Finally I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting empty array because you are passing name instead of id

change your `<select>` as below:

```
<select class="district col-md-3 center-block" id="zone">
<?php 
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_zones)) {
        echo "<option value='".$res['id']."'>".$res['name']."</option>"; //<-----Add id instead of name
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

pass in `json encode $arr` instead of `"data"=>$arr`

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

becouse `$arr` is also an array